# DBT join multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, dbt

I am learning DBT, specifically dbt-mysql. I am having trouble combining several tables into one table.
What I want to do:
Group By several columns by the last_updated (timestamp) date of the table and then combine those columns into a single table by the split last_updated field. Here is how I want my data to end up:

[image]

Here is my staging model (which I think should be straight selects from the database):

staging/clients/stg_clients_fields.sql

```
SELECT id, created, last_updated, service, order_count, spent_count, deleted, country
FROM client_database.clients
```

Then I have intermediate models (which I think should reconstruct data for my needs):
intermediate/clients/clients_last_updated_grouped.sql

```
SELECT YEAR(last_updated) as year_updated, MONTH(last_updated) as month_updated, COUNT(id) as client_count
FROM {{ ref('stg_clients_fields') }}
GROUP BY YEAR(last_updated), MONTH (last_updated)
```

intermediate/clients/clients_deleted_grouped.sql

```
SELECT YEAR(last_updated) as year_updated, MONTH(last_updated) as month_updated, COUNT(id) as deleted
FROM {{ ref('stg_clients_fields') }}
WHERE deleted = 1
GROUP BY YEAR(last_updated), MONTH (last_updated)
```

intermediate/clients/clients_service_grouped.sql

```
SELECT YEAR(last_updated) as year_updated, MONTH(last_updated) as month_updated, COUNT(id) as service
FROM {{ ref('stg_clients_fields') }}
WHERE service IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY YEAR(last_updated), MONTH (last_updated)
```

And other columns follow the same pattern based on their WHERE clauses.

Now I need to create a marts model that would use all previously created data and put it in one single table.

At this point, I end up with several tables that have the last_updated field separated and the specific column value next to the date.

How can I now combine all these tables that they would join on the last_updated split into to columns field?

Or perhaps there is a better solution to group data by year and month and get individual column values based on conditions?

I am new to DBT so all the help and all advice are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `clients_last_updated_grouped` doesn't have a `where` condition, it's guaranteed to have all of the year/month combinations found in the other models. This makes it much easier. You can just select from that model and join the other models on year and month:

```sql
with
    updated as (select * from {{ ref('clients_last_updated_grouped') }} ),
    deleted as (select * from  ),
    service as (select * from  ),

    joined as (
        select
            updated.year,
            updated.month,
            updated.client_count,
            coalesce(deleted.deleted, 0) as deleted_count,
            coalesce(service.service, 0) as service_count

        from
            updated
            left join deleted on updated.year = deleted.year and updated.month = deleted.month
            left join service on updated.year = service.year and updated.month = service.month
    )
select *
from joined
```

If your database doesn't support CTEs (`with ...`), this becomes:

```
select
    updated.year,
    updated.month,
    updated.client_count,
    coalesce(deleted.deleted, 0) as deleted_count,
    coalesce(service.service, 0) as service_count

from
    {{ ref('clients_last_updated_grouped') }} as updated
    left join {{ ref('clients_deleted_grouped') }} as deleted on updated.year = deleted.year and updated.month = deleted.month
    left join {{ ref('clients_service_grouped') }} as service on updated.year = service.year and updated.month = service.month
```

If it's not the case that `clients_last_updated_grouped` has every month/year combination of the other tables, you would need to first construct a "[date spine](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils/blob/main/macros/sql/date_spine.sql)", and then left join all 3 tables to that date spine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have MySQL version of 5.7.31 and WITH clause is not supported by it. Your query seems perfect, will try it after changing WITH clause to something else, and if it will work - accept the answer, thanks!

Comment: I'll amend the answer -- it's easy to avoid using CTEs